# Change values of user input in hook_field_validate?

Tags: entities

I have setup a custom field and have a validater setup for it. I would like to be able to adjust and actually change the user input from within my validator. so say this is a multi value field, each set of values shows up in $item. I have adjusted and changed the values in this function, but how I can I save them and make sure the rest of the form processes using the changed values?

```
mycustomfield_field_validate($obj_type, $object, $field, $instance,$langcode,   &$items, &$errors){

  foreach($items as $item){
  // validation check is here
  }    
}
```

Comment: This may be useful: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/7172/validating-and-modifying-form-data-simultaneously

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps [hook_field_attach_submit](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_attach_submit/7) can be used in your case?